How to Extract GeoGebra Script from a GGB File?
I would like to know if there is any way to extract the GeoGebra script from a GGB file, and whether this script can restore the original effects as closely as possible.
Currently, the basic logic is to iterate through all objects, obtain each object's Command and value, and then generate the corresponding script.
const allObjects = ggbApplet.getAllObjectNames(); // Get all object names
let ggbScript = '';

allObjects.forEach(objName => {
    const commandString = ggbApplet.getCommandString(objName, false);

    const objType = ggbApplet.getObjectType(objName);
    let scriptLine;

    if (commandString) {
        scriptLine = `${objName} = ${commandString}`;
    } else {
        const valueString = ggbApplet.getValueString(objName);
        scriptLine = `${valueString}`;
    }

    ggbScript += scriptLine + '\n';
});

The extracted commands look like this:
A = Intersect[xAxis, yAxis]
B = Point[xAxis]
a = Ray[A, B]
C = Point[a]
C' = Mirror[C, A]
c = Semicircle[C, C']
D = Intersect[c, yAxis]
d = CircleArc[A, D, C]

However, there are many issues, and often fails to execute. For example, some objects need to have their properties set, such as the position of points, visibility, line type, or whether the object's title is displayed. However, not all types of objects should have every property set, as this would make the script too long, and most properties are default values anyway.
To ensure that the generated script runs correctly and restores the original effects as much as possible, I have made many modifications to the code above. For instance, I set specific coordinates for movable points, add property settings for certain types of objects, and adjust the logic of organizing scriptLine for some special types of variables.
Am I approaching this the right way, or is there a better method?

I also tried parsing   and  tags within the  section from geogebra.xml, but different commands might require different parsing approaches, so my code is becoming more and more complex, but it still can't adapt to most of the ggb files.
